# Issue extracting array nested in a dictionary and return publishers for it with Combine and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am implementing a network layer using combine and having a hard time extracting the inner array as the publisher in the type I need in a single swipe. I have it working but as 2 separate functions where on the second within .sink I pull what I need but I want it all to happen within the 1st function... current state for reference below.

json returned from api for reference:

```
     {
            "count": 1,
            "entities": [
    {facetids:[],
    identifiers:[],
    description:String},
    {facetids:[],
    identifiers:[],
    description:String}
]
        }
```

What Entities looks like:

```
struct Entities:Decodable
{
    var count:Int?
    var entities: [Entity]?
}
```

NetworkController.swift:

```
 func get<T>(type: T.Type, url: URL, headers: Headers) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> where T : Decodable
    {
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    headers.forEach
    {
        key, value in
        
        if let value = value as? String
        {
            urlRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
    }
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

EntitiesLogicController.swift:

```
    func getEntities(named: String, count: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Entities, Error> {
    let endpoint = Endpoint.companies(named: named, count: count)
    
    return networkController.get(type: Entities.self, url: endpoint.url, headers: endpoint.headers)
}
```

ApiCaller.swift:

```
  func getEntities(named: String)
    {
        entitiesLogicController?.getEntities(named: named, count: 20).sink{
        [weak self] completion in

        
        if case let .failure(error) = completion
        {
            print("Error retrieving Entity, ERROR: \(error)")
        } else if case .finished = completion
        {
            print("Data successfully downloaded")
        }
    } receiveValue:
    {
        requestedEntity in
        
        do{
            let entities:[Entity] = try requestedEntity.entities!.compactMap{
                entity in
                do
                {
                    return try Entity(from: entity)
                }
            }
            self.entities = entities
        }catch
        {
            print("Error")
        }
    }.store(in: &subscriptions)
}
```

I want/need the get to return AnyPublisher<[T], Error> instead
where [T] == [Entity] decodable structs work perfectly fine and everything else as well.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want easily. The way your code is structured your generic functions can only return the root type of your json. Using a subscriber chained to your network operation is probably the simplest way. You could change your function so that you could pass in a `Keypath` and its type, but I think that is probably going to be unnecessarily complicated. The other thing you could do is use a custom decoding function for your `Entities` Extracts the `[Entities]`

Comment: So through an operator in the network controller operation chained is what I was thinking and have been trying but keep hitting errors. Ideally an operator chained in:  return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .eraseToAnyPublisher().   Is what I want and have been trying to get done.

Comment: Your mapping has to take place outside of the generic function, because it is only at that point that you know the specific data that you want.  I don't really see any way that is better than what you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `the get to return AnyPublisher<[T], Error> instead where [T] == [Entity]` then you should have a generic LogicController which will handle a generic call instead of `EntitiesLogicController.swift`

GenericLogicController.swift

```
func getObjects<T>(parameters: [String: Any]) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> where T : Decodable {

    let endpoint = //create a genric endpoint - or use switch to differentiate
    return networkController.get(type: T.self, url: endpoint.url, headers: endpoint.headers)

}
```

Comment: The network controller is generic, the logic controller already handles multiple types that are differentiated, I tried your approach and that did not work at all.

Comment: I know the network controller is generic, where do you want ` the get to return AnyPublisher<[T], Error> instead where [T] == [Entity]` happen? because your approach is already fine

Comment: Instead of generating it within ApiCaller I want it generated within an operator in the network controller and returned by it to the logic controller which in return should return it to the observable view model.